# How to add submenu's in table view in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

i don no whether this question asked or not but i still searching for an answer.Am working in tableview concept and i am creating a table view like with some set of menu's like inbox, sent,setting etc.Now what i want is i want to create sub menu's inside every menu, for example if i click inbox it should show new,replied,deleted etc like this for every main menu i want to create sub menu. Using array we can load by checking section but with out using array i want to create directly and notable one i have used custom cell i also want to show images as per the menu if it is inbox i have to show inbox image. Could any one help me??

```
    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 8;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 8;

}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellidentifier=@"ViewProfileCell";

    MyHomeViewCell *cell= [[MyHomeViewCell alloc] init];

    cell=(MyHomeViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];

    if(!cell)
    {
NSArray *nibofMyHomeCell=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MyHomeViewCell" owner:self options:Nil];
        cell=[nibofMyHomeCell objectAtIndex:0];


    }

    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
        cell.MyHomeMenuLabel.text=@"Inbox";
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a  UITableview which will contain cells on it as you said inbox, sent, setting etc.

After you need to create another UITableView which will contain your submenu buttons or labels like new,replied, deleted when click on inbox.

Simillarly you will do for rest of the cells in your main UITableView.

And don't get confuse on how will i identify which tableview will get called.

You will check for tableview name like below:

```
 if(tableView==main)
    {
    ///Code for main menu tableview.
    }
    else if(tableView==sub)
    {
    ////Code for submenu tableview. 
    }
```

This you will do in all UITableView Delegate and Datasource methods:

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Creating new tableView will be easier locally instead of handling custom cell and for what you want to create custom cell?

Answer (score 1):

Here ara a good tuts it could help you:

[Expanding/Collapsing TableView Sections](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/)

[Expandable UITableView](http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=338)

And this github awesome code [here](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/UIExpandableTableView) by Oliver Letterer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this. You could for example show each item as a section header and if the section header is tapped you show (or hide) all of the rows in that section. The rows being the 'sub menu' items (new, replied, deleted). Or you could use different sections for each part and how or hide the sections. Or show and hide rows. This is pretty much all controlled by changing the section and row counts.